# Syntax error: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list line

Tags: google-apps-script, debugging, google-sheets, syntax-error

I am facing an issue while saving the script in Google Sheets. The script is about copying data from other sheets to the master sheet. Please help me, the script is as below;

```
`function myFunction() {
// ={FILTER{{'Partial Data 1' !A2:G, "Data Tab 1 - Row "&RDW('Partial Data 1' !A2:A)}. 'Partial Data 1' !A2:A<>"");
// FILTER{{'Partial Data 2' !A2:G, "Data Tab 2 - Row "&ROW{'Partial Data 2' !A2:A)}. 'Partial Data 2' !A2:A<>"");
// FILTER({'Partial Data 3' !A2:G, "Data Tab 3 • Row "&ROW('Partial Data 3' !A2:A)}. 'Partial Data 3' !A2:A<>"")}


// (s => 'FILTER({'${s.getSheetName()}' !${dataRange}, "${s.getSheetName()} • Row "&ROW('${s.getSheetName()}' !${checkRange})}. '${s.getSheetName()}' !${checkRange}<>"")')


//set variables
const masterSheet = "Master";
const masterSheetFormulaCell = "A2";
const ignoreSheets = ["Copy of Master"];
const dataRange = "A2:G";
const checkRange = "A2:A";
//end set variables

const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
ignoreSheets.push(masterSheet);
const allSheets = ss.getSheets(); I
const filteredlistOfSheets = allSheets.filter(s => ignoreSheets.indexOf(s.getSheetName()) == -1);

let formulaArray = filteredlistOfSheets.map(ss => 'FILTER({'${s.getSheetName()}' !${dataRange}, "${s.getSheetName()} • Row "&ROW('${s.getSheetName()}' !${checkRange})}. '${s.getSheetName()}' !${checkRange}<>"")')

let formulaText = "={" + formulaArray.join(";") + "}";

//co
```

nsole.log(formulaText);
ss.getSheetByName(masterSheet).getRange(masterSheetFormulaCell).setFormula(formulaText);
}`

The code is learned from youtube tutorial and tried everything including rewrite, but could not able fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in the use of single and double quotes, and Templated Literals.  With Templated literals use the back tick for the whole string then inside the `${}` will be replaced in the string with the variable.  I'm not sure if your formula will work.

**Try changing**

```
let formulaArray = filteredlistOfSheets.map(ss => 'FILTER({'${s.getSheetName()}' !${dataRange}, "${s.getSheetName()} • Row "&ROW('${s.getSheetName()}' !${checkRange})}. '${s.getSheetName()}' !${checkRange}<>"")');
```

**To this**

```
let formulaArray = filteredlistOfSheets.map(ss => `FILTER(${s.getSheetName()}!${dataRange},${s.getSheetName()} • Row!&ROW(${s.getSheetName()}!${checkRange}).${s.getSheetName()}!${checkRange}<>"")`);
```

**Reference**

- [Templated Literals](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-template-literals-in-javascript)